# Can I access the data from an iPhone's gyroscope inside an in-app advertisement?

Tags: javascript, iframe, accelerometer, gyroscope, mraid

I develop ads and recently ran into an interesting problem. I am trying to create an ad that uses an iPhones gyroscope to move around a panoramic image as the user moved their phone. The ad I am making is inserted into an app as an HTML5 iframe. Everything works perfectly when the iframe is on a browser but in the iframe in the app the gyroscope and accelerometer seem to do nothing. I have access to MRAID and Admob methods but I am not sure of the best way to accomplish my goal. I have heard conflicting things such as iOS restricts the gyroscope data from ads but I don't think this is correct. If anyone has any experience working on this I would appreciate the help. Just trying to hook into the gyroscope from a web view.

Thank you.

Comment: Sir, I just came across same issue. Have you solved it anyhow within passing year?

Comment: Kind of.. you have to use MRAID or some sort of 3rd party SDK. For me the SDK was not an option so the best thing is usually to come up with some sort of creative javascript solution using the MRAID data available to you. I actually haven't revisited this idea but using MRAID I successfully built a fairly complicated parallax implementation which otherwise would have been impossible. Sadly however, it still appears most device information is unavailable inside the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't find any relevant information about gyroscope in mraid device information, their documentation seems quite less developer friendly than others.